# How do I add an array of objects into an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am gathering JSON string data on a button click. Each time I click the button another product gets added to the array. The array is an array of objects:

```
{SKU: "9372983-382L", retail_price: "11.75", list_price: "3.50", product_name: "Tennis balls"}
```

How would I take this information and insert it into a table? say I have

```
<div id='table'>
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var prodArr=[{SKU: "9372983-382L", retail_price: "11.75", list_price: "3.50", 
product_name: "Tennis balls"}];

function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    const arr = data;
    for(var obj of arr){
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var val of Object.values(obj)){
            var col = document.createElement('td');
            col.textContent = val;
            row.appendChild(col);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}

buildTable(prodArr);
```

I would like to add headers for SKU:, retail_price:, list_price: product_name: and a textbox for quantity on each row as well.

Comment: What have you tried? We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting. Also, nesting the table within a `div` is redundant. Just give the table the `id` and lose the `div`.

Comment: Do you happen to know about [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method? What about [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property? Any ideas?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov It's `document`, not `Document`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Postman507/pen/MWjQpKR - This is what I have so far, I would like to add headers for SKU: product_name: list_price: retail_price: quantity: but quantity is not listed here so i'd like a textbox inserted in place. I have also updated my original code to match this codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the array, use `Object.values` to loop over the values of the object, and use `document.createElement` to create new table rows to add to the table.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const arr = [{SKU: "9372983-382L", retail_price: "11.75", list_price: "3.50", product_name: "Tennis balls"}];
for(const obj of arr){
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  for(const val of Object.values(obj)){
    const col = document.createElement('td');
    col.textContent = val;
    row.appendChild(col);
  }
  table.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: We tend not to provide answers to poor questions that don't belong here in the first place as it just attracts more poor questions.